# What does exit do in an if block in a shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, exit

I have a question regarding unix shell script.

Say if you do `exit 1` in inner `if`: will it exit or will it still execute the outer `if`? The following is a dummy example.

```
if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
    if [ "$PASSWORD" -gt 10]; then
        echo "password is too large!"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "You have access!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I assume that those semantics are specific to the used shell. Which shell is executing the script?

Comment: that was just example, but developing for kshell.

Comment: It would probably have been faster to just test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exit` is usually a shell built-in, so in theory it does depend on which shell you're using.  However, I'm not aware of any shell where it operates other than exiting the current process.  From the bash man page,

```
   exit [n]
          Cause the shell to exit with a status of n.  If  n  is  omitted,
          the exit status is that of the last command executed.  A trap on
          EXIT is executed before the shell terminates.
```

So it doesn't simply end the current `if` clause, it exits the whole shell (or process, in essence, since the script is being run within a shell process).

From man sh,

```
 exit [exitstatus]
        Terminate the shell process.  If exitstatus is given it is used as
        the exit status of the shell; otherwise the exit status of the
        preceding command is used.
```

And lastly, from man ksh,

```
   † exit [ n ]
          Causes  the  shell  to exit with the exit status specified by n.
          The value will be the least significant 8 bits of the  specified
          status.   If  n  is omitted, then the exit status is that of the
          last command executed.  An end-of-file will also cause the shell
          to  exit  except for a shell which has the ignoreeof option (see
          set below) turned on.
```

Answer (score 9):

`exit` terminates the calling process. In most circumstances, this exits the whole script, even if you call it from inside a loop, a function or an included script. The only shell constructs that “catch” `exit` are the ones that introduce a subshell (i.e. a [forked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) child shell process):

- the basic subshell construct `(…)` that executes the command inside the parentheses in a subshell;
- the command substitution construct `$(…)` (and its deprecated equivalent, the backquotes `` `…` ``), which executes a command and returns its output as a string;
- background jobs forked with `&`;
- the left-hand side of a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) `|`, and the right-hand side as well on most shells (ATT ksh and zsh being the exceptions);
- some shells have other subprocess constructs, for example process substitution `<(…)`, `>(…)`, etc., on ksh, bash and zsh.

You can break out of a `while` or `for` loop with the `break` keyword, and you can break out of a function with the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` will end the script completely.

`break` will go one level higher in loops - but not in if-statements (according to my bash-manpage).